# Extending codeigniter helper methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have been developing a project in codeigniter, and I need to change the functionality of a function called `site_url()` of `url_helper`. I have already extended the `url_helper` in my application/helper folder by naming it `MY_url_helper`, and I can load/access it. What I want to know is, How can I extend the functionality of `site_url()` function. Do I need to create another method with different name called `site_url_ext()` in my extended helper, or is there a way to extend the current function.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to change on this specific function ?

Comment: I need to change the returning url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you need to understand what "Extending" basically means. By extending a helper class, you get exposed to the functionality the helper class is offering, which means that you don't have to re-write it. You cannot extend (as in **inherit**) a function / method.
If you would like to add more functionality to the already existing `site_url()` function, you can create your own separate function and name it as you wish e.g. `site_url_ext()`, copy the code in the original `site_url()` if need be and start modifying from there on-wards. Alternatively code your own `site_url_ext()` altogether.
If it's just the `base_url` you would like to modify then do only that in the constructor of the `url_helper` class.

Comment: Thanks, Now I understand that it can only be done with classes and helpers aren't classes.

Comment: Great, you can also modify the actual `site_url()` function if need be just be sure that this is your navigation point for your entire system so changes here are critical.